# Use Spring Security 3 inside Struts 2 application. Good choose?

Tags: java, struts2, spring-security, web

At this moment I think about authentication in my web app based on Strust2.

And I know only one instrument for this: Spring Security 3.

So, what can you recommended? It is good variant use Struts 2 with Spring Security 3 together or maybe in my case, I must use something else? There is more good choose?

Thanks.

Comment: its a good choice.and Struts2 is independent of what you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security is a good choice for any java based web application. Its lightweight, pluggable and easy to configure too. But to evaluate several alternatives and then decides what suits you best is always better and sensible choice.

Apart from Spring Security, there is [Apache Shrio](http://shiro.apache.org/) and its [worth evaluating](http://www.infoq.com/articles/apache-shiro). There have been comparisons ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991084/shiro-vs-springsecurity),[2](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?105509-Apache-Shiro-vs-Spring-Security)) between these two frameworks. Just like Spring security Shrio is also easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you need *very* light weight security, just basic authentication it is very easy to do your self there is also the struts2 roles interceptor but if you need anything better then what you propose is the way to go.